# Use a field's values in database to populate an exposed filter's options

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type with a field named year (integer).

In a view, I'd like to expose this field to the user as a filter.

Instead of the default text boxes, I want to populate select lists with the values in the database for that field. Then the user will just have to click to select.

My php code writing is on copy-paste level.

I am using D7.

Answer (score 0):

This [topic](http://www.ys1.ru/blog/select-v-views-exposed-filter) migth be useful for you.

You can also create taxonomy vocabulary years and than select filter will be able to use in views.